# Upgrade to TFS 2017 HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized

Tags: iis, tfs, tfs-2015

I have a Windows Server 2012 machine that is on our domain here at owrk. I upgraded our TFS from TFS2015 to TFS2017. When I try to open the dashboard in the web browser I get an HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Detailed info (below) seems to be complaining about IIS and such. This all worked before the upgrade so I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what to do. Any help appreciated

*Detailed Error Information:
Module    WindowsAuthenticationModule 
Notification    AuthenticateRequest 
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 
Error Code    0x8009030e 
Requested URL    http://ourserver03:8080/tfs/Common Instrument Framework/myteam/_dashboards

Physical Path    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 15.0\Application Tier\Web Services\Common Instrument Framework\Greylock\LI 5 Team_dashboards 
Logon Method    Not yet determined 
Logon User    Not yet determined 
More Information:
This error occurs when either the username or password supplied to IIS is invalid, or when IIS cannot use the username and password to authenticate the user.*

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix:

Went into the IIS Service manager and stopped the Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool. Wait until it completely shuts down and then restart it. After that everything seemed to work